# How can I center the title in a console window vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to center text in the console title in VB.NET? I have scoured the forums but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look this link, I hope this help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/153af4c9-3166-404d-b04c-ef6ac0b52f6f/how-to-automatically-center-text-in-a-console-application?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Thanks but unless I am missing something this talks about centering text in the console rather than the title bar "Console.Title"

Comment: I've never done, I would try to apply the formats to the console.title instead to the console itself. I Hope it works.